# Call to a member function getIdProcesoAcumulado() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i'm getting this error when i try to check if an id already exist on certain table, but i get the error "Call to a member function getIdProcesoAcumulado() on a non-object"

This is the controller:

```
public function AcumularAction($id){
    $idAcumulado = $this->getRequest()->get('acumulado');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $proceso =$em->getRepository('ProcesoBundle:ProcesoDisciplinario')->find($id);
    $acumulado = $em->getRepository('ProcesoBundle:ProcesoDisciplinario')->find($idAcumulado);
    $existe = $em->getRepository('ProcesoBundle:ProcesoAcumulado')->find($idAcumulado);
    $acum = new ProcesoAcumulado();
    $existe->getIdProcesoAcumulado();
    if(! $acumulado){
        return new JsonResponse(array('exito' => false));
    }else{
        $acum->setIdProcesoAcumulado($acumulado);
        $acum->setIdProceso($proceso);
        //$acum->setNroInternoAcum();
        $em->persist($acum);
        $em->flush();
        return new JsonResponse(array('exito' => true));
    }
}
```

and this is the get:

```
/**
 * Get idProcesoAcumulado
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIdProcesoAcumulado()
{
    return $this->idProcesoAcumulado;
}
```

Comment: Try `dump($existe);` It's probably `NULL`. If so, it's because `$em->getRepository('ProcesoBundle:ProcesoAcumulado')->find($idAcumulado);` does not return desired entity.

Answer (score 1):

If this object $existe is null I can not get the value ->getIdProcesoAcumulado().

Try:

```
if($existe){
    $existe->getIdProcesoAcumulado();
}
```